# No SIM Card detected, Emergency Call Only After Flashing Custom ROM AND Stock ROM [Sony Xperia AcroS]

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, sim-card, sony-xperia, stock-rom

Yesterday i've decided to check some of the custom ROMs for my Sony Xperia Acro S.
With locked bootloader i installed a CWM Recovery and flashed a ROM.

The ROM Worked and the signal worked and i've made few calls to check if it is working or not.

i decided to check another ROM, it caused a bootloop.
so by using the Flashtool i flashed the stock ROM again and installed the recovery again and flashed the first Custom ROM again to check it out more.

Sadly, the mobile says "Emergency call only" and " No SIM detected ".
i tried the SIM card on another phone and it's working.

so, i flashed the STOCK ROM that i used to flash many times and it should be 100% working, but NO, The problem is still there.

when i check for the IMEI number by the  * # 06 #  it says "no newtork connection "

I Can't find a solution online, so please help me.

**TL;DR**

**Things i have made before the problem:**

1. Flashed a Custom ROM had a bootloop, Flashed the Stock ROM and then Flashed another Working Custom ROM.

**Things i have made trying to FIX:**

1. Flashed the 4.1 Stock ROM.
2. Flashed the Old Android 4.0 ROM and updated it via Sony's PC Companion.
3. Checked the IMEI Number = fail to find and it says "No Network Connection"

Comment: look under settings > about phone search for modem version or radio version ,tell me whaat it say

Comment: I Can't find " modem version or radio version", but here is an album of screenshots of my "settings > about phone" : http://imgur.com/yIxlCej,ZpVp51n,1KkVQgz

Comment: and here is the *#*#INFO#*#* Screenshot : http://imgur.com/J0EN10S

Comment: yes my apologies on sony it's called "baseband version" I am currentlly reading more about your device will be back in a few

Comment: is your phone bought unlocked or did you unlocked it ? I am talking about the simlock not the bootloader

Comment: No, it was brought unlocked.

Comment: did you try the option repair my phone on PC companion ? if not try it out it is available when no phone is pluged to pc the device selection is made manualy

Comment: i will try it now, also thanks for your efforts.
And, speaking of sim locking, my memory betrays me but i don't remember if i excluded the TA file -which contain a file called sim_lock- from the Stock Rom flashing.
i always exclude it but i don't remember if i excluded it in the time the problem occurred.
maybe it is the key !?

Comment: might be ,but I am sure of one thing it's something to do with the baseband or the simlock ,that's why I suggest using the pc companion feature it will reinstall every thing to latest stable stock if that fix the problem fine ,if not we will call it stone one and build on it

Comment: Okay, I am currently downloading the software via PC Companion and waiting to connect my phone.
But if PC Companion is going to install the latest stable software, isn't it the same as flashing the stock rom i used to flash for many times ?

Comment: may be it's the same may be it' not ,I just wanna be sure the firmware if 100% sony's ,we never know if the firmware you flashed is 100% stock and the pc companion update may leave some stuff as they were but the repair feature will reflash every thing ,it's just to try to isolate the problem so we know for sure it's nothing to do with the firmware

Comment: Okay, sorry i am late.
I Finished the PC Companion repair and sadly no the problem isn't yet solved.

so, what is the next step ?

Comment: one curious thing in your INFO screenshot ... are you Under a WCDMA network ?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This fix was temporary. The problem returned the next day. Sorry.

After I flashed Cyanogenmod 12.1(upgraded to lollipop) to my nexus 5 I had the "no Sim Card". It is a very popular problem for this ROM or Lollipop in general. I try shimming the sim, Updating PRL etc... and nothing was working.

Here is what I think finally fixed it for me:

In dialer keypad: `*#*#72786#*#*`     (this will wipe the carrier settings)

`reboot` if your phone didn't automatically. Your phone will go through activation in about 5 minutes, re-gathering the *correct* carrier settings just like when you first bought it.

Tip was found here:
https://help.ting.com/hc/en-us/articles/205428508-Completing-Activation-for-Your-Nexus-5-or-6

Hope this helps someone, anyone.

Comment: Did not work for me on Xperia SP, even temporarily

Comment: Did not work for me on Huawei Y5 2017 MYA-L13 HWMYA-L6737, even temporarily