# "No SIM Card" after flashing custom ROM (Oneplus 7 Pro)

Tags: sim-card, oneplus-7-pro

I have an unlocked Oneplus 7 Pro that I just installed Havoc OS on, which stopped the SIM card from being recognized. This SIM card works on both other phones (stock Pixel 2) and this phone with a stock ROM. The phone still has its two IMEI numbers. I've looked at quite a few options to fix this, such as:

- Rebooting the phone multiple times
- Clearing Dalvik/Cache
- Resetting all network settings in Settings > System > Reset options
- [Reflashing the ROM and TWRP multiple times to make sure they are in both slots](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-7-pro/help/phone-isnt-detecting-sim-card-install-t4088121)
- Trying dial codes [*#*#72786#*#*](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/116739/) and *#*#4636#*#* (both cleared the input but nothing happened afterwards, no menus or popups)
- [Taking out the sim, putting it in airplane mode, putting the sim back in, powering off, waiting a minute, and putting it back in](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2698621)
- [The device was sim unlocked before flashing the ROM](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-7-pro/help/sim-card-detected-installing-lineageos-t4106511)

Comment: You phone has a dual-SIM slot. Are you sure your ROM supports both SIM slots? May be the ROM only support one of the slots and currently your SIM is seated in the wrong slot?

Comment: @Robert That could be the case, but the phone only came with a tray for one SIM, which I assumed to be the primary one. I also just checked the two IMEIs again, and they both seem to be the same as the one printed onto the back of the phone.